# How to handle a redirect response with authentication in node.js?

Tags: javascript, http, node.js

for learning purposes I'm not using external modules, so I'm trying to do an authentication request to a server. It works with curl :

```
curl -L -u user:password http://webpage/email
```

[SOLVED, thansk ... ]But in node.js I have problems , this is my code :

```
var http = require("http");
var options = {
  hostname : 'webpage',
  port : '80',
  path : '/email',
  method : 'GET',
  headers : {
       "Connection" : "keep-alive",
       "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)"
  },
  auth : "username:password"
}

options.agent = new http.Agent(options);

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
 // The authentication works fine, like curl without -L parameter
 // STATUS 302
 res.setEncoding('utf8');
 res.on('data',function(chunk){
  console.log(chunk);

 // SOLVED ! 

  var opts = {
   host : 'webpage',
   port : '80',
   path : '/email/',
   location : res.headers.location,
   auth : "user:password"
 }

 var require = http.request(opts,function(resp){
  resp.setEnconding("utf8");
  resp.on('data',function(chk){
   console.log(chk);
  });
 });

 require.end();
 // --------------

  // I got the same without -L parameter in curl
  // <head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
  // <body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a href="http://webpage/email/">here</a></body> <-- The 'Location' is the same

 });
});

req.on('error',function(e){
 console.log('Problem with request : ' + e.message);
}

req.end()
```

I tried to request again with 'Location' in header, but I got the same result.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I know you said you solved this already, but it still deserves an answer for others.

Answer (score 1):

The -u in curl allows you to pass the value for the Authentication header. In node, you would do this manually. The spec for Basic Authentication (which I assume you're using) says pass the credentials in base 64 encoded format. Doing this manually in node looks something like this.

```
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(user + ':' + pass)).toString('base64')
}
```

Comment: I think so that the name of the header is "Authorization", when I did this request with node v.0.4.7 (for heroku), I got errors because the auth property doesn't exists in that version so I tried with "Authorization" header and works fine.